# How to go back to previous of current page without using session or javascript in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I want to go to the previous of the current page in View and Controller without storing URL in session or using **javascript which loads not updated page from cache**.

previous page is users.php
current page is editUser.php

this is my current part of the code.

I tried using this in View:

```
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">Go Back</a>
```

But it loads the same page.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>usersListing">Go Back</a>
```

And one more thing is in Controller I am using this to load previous page:

```
redirect('usersListing');
```

Is there something like `redirect_back()` built-in?

Comment: I am already defining this <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>usersListing"> why would I use session to define again. I am finding minimized and efficient code

Comment: http reffer stores the current url, where i want to load prevoius url where the current page came from

Comment: you have missed echo  here <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>">Go Back</a>

Comment: you already have the components here. just redirect to the referer. please note, doing this isn't reliable.

Comment: thank you @SangitaKendre its working now!

Answer (score 0):

You could pass in a GET parameter `editUser.php?ref=users.php` since `Referrer` is not reliable. You won't have that built-in. You will need to manually `redirect($_GET['ref'])`. If you do that, you need to make sure you won't get into `users.php?ref=http://external.url.example.com/`

Understand that the request to `editUser.php` is totally separate from the one to `users.php`. So in order for going back to have some meaning, the "previous" needs to be defined somewhere. If you do this with javascript, you rely on the history that stored the "previous". If you do this through a session, you rely on it to store the "previous". So if you don't want to use either one of them, you need to come up with another solution, hence my proposal to use of a `ref` parameter. You can as well use the HTTP_REFERER but, again, you need to verify it is not an external url.